# Using the parser combinator crate "nom" to partially read and parse a file

Tags: parsing, rust, immutability, nom

I have a usecase where I only want to parse the beginning of a file to to the point where I decide to stop parsing. This can be 4kB or more. The exact amount is not known. So there is no need to read the whole file (which can be 100kB for instance).

All what I have seen in the most used parser combinator crate named "nom" is that there always whole chunks of bytes or characters are parsed which are complete in the memory.

The idea to build an own datastructure which dynamically reads from a file didn't work out well because I cannot override immutable self references as seen here:

```rust
  struct MyInput {
   pb : PathBuf,
   read : Box::<dyn Read>,
   filelength : u64,
   current_content : String,
  }


  impl MyInput {
   fn new( pb : PathBuf) -> Self{
    let file = OpenOptions::new().read(true).open(pb.clone()).unwrap();
    let filelength = std::fs::metadata(pb.clone()).unwrap().len();
    let current_content = "".to_string();
    Self { pb, read : Box::new( file), filelength, current_content}
   }
  }

  impl InputLength for MyInput {
   fn input_len(&self) -> usize {
    self.filelength as usize // here I have to tweake something later because char vs. u8
   }
  }

  // here lies the problem

  impl Compare<&str> for MyInput {
    fn compare(&self, t: &str) -> nom::CompareResult { 

      // I cannot fill a cache as I indended to do in self.current_content 
      // because &self is immutable
        todo!()
    }

    fn compare_no_case(&self, t: &str) -> nom::CompareResult {
        todo!()
    }
  }
```

Is there another solution for my problem?

Comment: Nom has support for parsing a [stream](https://crates.io/crates/nom#streaming-formats).

Comment: There is nowhere a possibilty to treat real streams. Even in this referred sozu project only u8 slices are parsed. In nom is an error Err::Incomplete(Needed) defined. If that occurs then I can try to get more data and parse from the beginning. This is not what I understand under stream parsing. Another possibility is maybe to use a slice from a memory mapped vector. But I don't know if this is efficient.

Comment: You say that "The exact amount [of data needed for parsing] is not known". Then how do you decide when to stop parsing? Could you share an example of data that you want to parse?

Comment: Lets say I want to parse an 'a' followed by 0 or more 'b' followed by one 'c' then I can stop parsing when there is no 'a' or when there is an 'a' followed by not 'b' or 'c' or when there is an 'a' followed by 0 or more 'b' and not followed by 'c' or when there is an 'a' followed by 0 or more 'b' followed by one 'c'. And the rest of the file is discarded. In the unsuccessfull cases nom parse should provide an error, and in the successfull cases not.

Comment: That is exactly what streaming API of `nom` provides. The `Incomplete` variant of the error will be returned if you feed the parser only `b"abbb"` bytes. Then if you haven't read the whole file, you can read another chunk and pass it to processing. And if you have read a whole file, then this _is_ a parsing error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this should be your preferred solution, but if you want to mutate `self`, and the interface of the trait gives you only a `&self`, you can use *interior mutability* pattern. For example `RefCell`. Read [this detailed explanation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html) of it in The Book to learn more about it. But for quick snippet you could use this. Note that this will add a small runtime overhead of tracking the number of `RefCell` references.

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::ops::DerefMut;

struct Inner {
    pb : PathBuf,
    read : Box::<dyn Read>,
    filelength : u64,
    current_content : String,
}

struct MyInput {
    inner: RefCell<Inner>,
}

impl Compare<&str> for MyInput {
    fn compare(&self, t: &str) -> nom::CompareResult {
        // The call to deref_mut is only to show that you can obtain
        // a mutable reference to inner. 
        let inner: &mut Inner = self.inner.borrow_mut().deref_mut();

        todo!();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't like the Refcell variant. Maybe I will use other crates like combine or chumsky.

Comment: I agree that this is not a good solution. But this is the only one I can give you from the information you provided.